# <button> submittting on firefox, prevent default

Tags: javascript, html, events

I have a `<button>` with `onclick` function. And i need to pass a param to the function like this:

```
function go(id){
    dosomething();
}
```

But i do no why, on firefox `<button>` do the submit on form when is pressed.

So i need to prevent the default behavior, but i don't know how do it without passing the `event` param to function. And i don't know how to pass a param and event param to function together.

```
return false;
```

Doen't work to me.

I have this:

```
<button id="qtd" class="btn btnqtdmais inline qtdinputbtn" onclick="soma(<?=$item['dados']['id']?>)">+</button>
```

And the function:

```
function soma(id){
    dosomething();
}
```

Comment: show us how the event handler is added

Comment: Can you please provide some real production code, these snippets are not telling the whole truth.

Comment: sure, i'll edit the question

Comment: You can do for example `onclick="go(event, 'id')"` and declare it like `function go(event, id)`

Comment: Try to add `type="button"` attribute for the button.

Comment: @LightStyle your solution worked to me, if you want make a answer and i'll mark it as right.

Comment: Glad to help, this is the purpose of SO(in my opinion). There is already an answer like mine, you can mark it, I'm not here for reputation :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

the event parameter should always be last

```
 function myfunction (id, event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    dosomething();
    return false;
 }
```

call the function like this

```
 button.onclick = function(e) { myfunction(id, e) };
```

or

```
 <button id="qtd" class="btn btnqtdmais inline qtdinputbtn" onclick="soma(<?=$item['dados']['id']?>, event)">+</button>
```

NOTE: I tried both with success on Firefox.

firefox event behavior is very weird, you must explicitly pass the event parameter or it won't work, unlike chrome and dare i say MS this will work without the parameter

```
function myfunction (id) {
  event.preventDefault();
  dosomething();
  return false;
 }
```

**EDIT:**
this also works

```
 function soma (event, id) {
    event.preventDefault();
    dosomething();
    return false;
 }
 <button id="qtd" class="btn btnqtdmais inline qtdinputbtn" onclick="soma(event, <?=$item['dados']['id']?>)">+</button>
```

Comment: It will not worked for me. if event parameter is the first argument then it works for me.

Comment: I've tryed with event as first param. I don't know if this way (on second param) will work. If you want edit your answer to next guy searching about it.

Answer (score 1):

try with `onclick="this.preventDefault(); go(id);"`

Answer (score 1):

You can try using a bit of javascript to suppress the default action of the button

```
if (form.addEventListener) {
  return form.addEventListener('submit', function(e) {
    return e.preventDefault();
  }, true);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Html code:

```
 <button type="button" id="btn1" onclick="return handleButton(event,'btnSearch');"/>
```

JavaScript code:

```
function handleButton(event, searchButtonId) {
    event = event || window.event;
    if (event.keyCode == 13) {
       alert("Enter key pressed");
    }
}
```

You have to pass the event argument as first argument to the function.
Hope it resolves your problem.